# Different output for http and www versions

Tags: http, iis, web-applications, dns, plesk

I have a domain ie: `foo.com`

when i type `http://foo.com` , it goes to  my app.

When i type `www.foo.com` it goes to default IIS page.

I am using plesk 9 for windows.

When i use nslookup to look up DNS they both point to same DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IIS application go to bindings, and make sure BOTH www.yourdomain.tld as well as yourdomain.tld are binded. (PS. This question might have been better off at serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1):

If the two domains points to the same IP address, it seems you need to properly configure the Host Headers of your IIS server.

Using Plesk, i think you just have to add a proper alias in the domain management page.

Answer (score 1):

Changes which made in domain's configuration directly in IIS(not via Plesk) will be reset in future(after domain configuration update in Plesk)

In Plesk 9 you can switch on 'www' for domain on Hosting settings page, there is check box "WWW prefix" from left of domain name.